# animate imageview like flying on the sky effect in iPhone

Tags: iphone, animation, uiview, uiimageview

I have an image view I wanna animate this image view in upward direction like it gives the feeling like rocket going in the sky effect.

Please share any ideas.

Thanks,

Ahmad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is my rocket

```
-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{

    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    UIImageView *imageView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"rocket.png"]];

    [imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(200, 480, 100, 100)];

    [self.view addSubview:imageView];


    [UIView animateWithDuration:7.0 animations:^(void) {

    [imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(200, -100, 100, 100)];

    }];

}
```

Comment: Boss,I have tried to give u,but It says I am not eligible to give as I am new to stack overflow,need 15 reputation.right?